# remove extra space between tab and line

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space between tab and horizontal line displayed. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yy1t6w1f/ . 
Sample code to create horizontal line:

```
div.hr {
background: #fff  no-repeat scroll center;
margin-left: 15em;
margin-right: 15em;
width:50em;
height:.05em;
}

div.hr hr {
display: none;
}
```

The created tab's should touch the horizontal line and their should be no space between tab and div.Thanks.

Comment: You should add: `hr { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: @emmanuel That should be an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use an `<hr>` for this.  I would use a border.

Comment: You have a lot of CSS that isn't used in that JSFiddle, @user222. For example, the selectors `div.hr hr` and `div.hr` are ignored because there are no div elements with class `hr` in your markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
hr { margin: 0; }
```

will do the trick. The `hr` tag in HTML has default margins, which are causing that space between those two elements. Note that the above code will remove all margins. If you only want the top margin removed, you can use `margin-top` instead of `margin`.

In fact, in your case, you need not use `hr` tag at all; you can remove it and simply add:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
```

to your `.tabDiv` CSS selector; that should also serve your purpose here.

Answer (score 3):

```
table, table td {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

hr { margin: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yy1t6w1f/6/

Comment: Post-edit: The table styles are unnecessary. All that is truly needed is `hr { margin-top: 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I’m misunderstanding what you are building, there is a far better way to write this.

See below:

```css
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-top: 2px solid #888;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
  
  min-width: 96px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
  
  font: 18px impact;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #3B0B17;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">FirstTab</a>
  <a href="">SecondTab</a>
  <a href="">ThirdTab</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (it's not what the OP asked for), and it also reintroduces spacing that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: There is no mention of the OP wishing to avoid horizontal spacing but it’s easy to remove if they want it gone. I’m demonstrating a better way to solve what looks to be the OPs bigger problem.

Comment: "their should be no space between tab and div." interprets to no space between the tabs.

Comment: That was not my interpretation. They wrote `div.hr` indicating that they thought the div was the hr. (We both know it is not but that is far from the only thing the OP was inconsistent on)